# In asp.net with sqlite set pragma Synchronous=Off

Tags: asp.net, sqlite

Try optimize Sqlite in an asp.net app by setting `Synchronous=Off` in the connection string, but keyword isn't supported https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/issues/147
https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/issues/354

Bottom of issue #354 suggests a solution with a pragma command towards the connection

```
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = true;";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Try to use this for `Synchronous`
https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous but uncertain where/how to obtain the correct connection corresponding to my `DbContext` type.

Answer (score 0):

Drop down to the ADO.NET connection in EF Core using code like this:

```cs
db.Database.OpenConnection();
try
{
    var connection = db.Database.GetDbConnection();

    // TODO: Use connection
}
finally
{
    db.Database.CloseConnection();
}
```